# How to enable dragging objects between Grids (without using ListView or GridView)?

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps

I've written a Windows Store-type app where you drag Player objects back and forth between two Grids (onField and Sideline). Worked great, but you could only move by (1) tap Player (2) tap target position. Then I decided I wanted to also let the user drag Players.  I tried adding a thumb to the Players  ... considered and rejected the possibility of using a Canvas.

All signs pointed to ListView or Gridview solutions, so I tried changing the onField and Sideline Grids to GridViews, but couldn't see any way to get the layout+sizing I wanted for the positions.  Finally, I put a Gridview in each cell of the big layout grids.  This worked, but at a cost of latency in moving Players between positions as well as lag in certain sorting operations.  Also, the drag operations only work if the initial drag direction is downward (???).

TLDR:  GridView and ListView solutions seem sub-par for my grid-to-grid drag-and-drop needs.

Answer (score 1):

In the WinRT xaml framework only GridView and ListView support drag and drop operations. I have no idea why but that's just the case.

This doesn't stop you creating your own but you really have to start from scratch which is a pain in the ass since you can't make use of the AllowDrop property etc.

You may have some luck porting the [Silverlight Drag and Drop library](http://silverlightdragdrop.codeplex.com/) to WinRT but it's not something I've tried.